# Is there any method i can add a scroll pane to a jlist that its added on a panel with null layout?

Tags: java, swing

I'm doing a school project based on a medical store and I want to add a scroll pane to all my 3 lists that I'm using

```
package Interfata;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing. * ;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Home extends JFrame {
    JPanel panelHome;
    static String[] listaplante = new String[10];
    static String[] listacantitati = new String[10];
    static String[] listapreturi = new String[10];
    static int kPlante = 0,
    kCantitati = 0,
    kPreturi = 0;
    JButton butonCumpara,
    butonAdauga;
    JTextField denumireField,
    pretField,
    cantitateField,
    cantitateDoritaField;

    public JPanel createHomeContentPane() {

        //Creez un panel pe care sa pun toate campurile.
        panelHome = new JPanel();
        panelHome.setLayout(null);
        panelHome.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 204, 255));
        panelHome.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Home"));

        //Creez lista cu plante
        DefaultListModel < String > listaPlante = new DefaultListModel < >();
        JList < String > list = new JList < >(citirePlante());
        list.setBounds(50, 75, 75, 100);
        list.setSelectionBackground(Color.ORANGE);
        panelHome.add(list);

        //Creez lista cu cantitatile fiecarei plante
        DefaultListModel < String > listaCantitati = new DefaultListModel < >();
        JList < String > list2 = new JList < >(citireCantitati());
        list2.setBounds(150, 75, 75, 100);
        list2.setSelectionBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        panelHome.add(list2);

        //Creez lista cu preturile fiecarei plante
        DefaultListModel < String > listaPreturi = new DefaultListModel < >();
        JList < String > list3 = new JList < >(citirePreturi());
        list3.setBounds(250, 75, 75, 100);
        list3.setSelectionBackground(Color.GREEN);
        panelHome.add(list3);

        //Creez titlurile pt fiecare lista
        JLabel denumireLabel = new JLabel("Denumire:");
        denumireLabel.setBounds(50, 55, 70, 20);
        panelHome.add(denumireLabel);

        JLabel cantitatiLabel = new JLabel("Cantitati:");
        cantitatiLabel.setBounds(150, 55, 70, 20);
        panelHome.add(cantitatiLabel);

        JLabel preturiLabel = new JLabel("Preturi:");
        preturiLabel.setBounds(250, 55, 70, 20);
        panelHome.add(preturiLabel);

        //Creez un camp pt a adauga cantitatea dorita care urmeaza a fi cumparata
        //cantitateDoritaField
        cantitateDoritaField = new JTextField();
        cantitateDoritaField.setBounds(80, 200, 100, 20);
        cantitateDoritaField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

        //placeholder pt cantitateField
        final String placeholderCantitateDorita = "Cantitatea dorita";
        cantitateDoritaField.setText(placeholderCantitateDorita);
        cantitateDoritaField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
            private boolean showingPlaceholder = true;
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                if (showingPlaceholder) {
                    showingPlaceholder = false;
                    cantitateDoritaField.setText("");
                }
            }
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
                if (cantitateDoritaField.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    cantitateDoritaField.setText(placeholderCantitateDorita);
                    showingPlaceholder = true;
                }
            }
        });
        panelHome.add(cantitateDoritaField);

        //Butonul de cumparare
        butonCumpara = new JButton("Cumpara");
        butonCumpara.setLocation(180, 200);
        butonCumpara.setSize(100, 20);
        butonCumpara.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                String plantaselectata = list.getSelectedValue();
                int indexplanta = list.getSelectedIndex();
                String cantitateselectata = list2.getSelectedValue();
                int indexcantitate = list2.getSelectedIndex();
                String pretselectat = list3.getSelectedValue();
                int indexpret = list3.getSelectedIndex();
                String cantitatedorita = cantitateDoritaField.getText();

                int valCantitate = Integer.valueOf(cantitateselectata);
                int valCantitateDorita = Integer.valueOf(cantitatedorita);
                int valPret = Integer.valueOf(pretselectat);

                if (indexplanta == indexcantitate && indexplanta == indexpret) {
                    if (valCantitateDorita <= valCantitate) {
                        try {
                            afisPlantaCumparata(plantaselectata, valCantitateDorita);
                        } catch(IOException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(Home.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                        int a = valCantitate - valCantitateDorita;
                        String b = Integer.toString(a);
                        listacantitati[indexcantitate] = b;
                        panelHome.setVisible(false);
                        panelHome.setVisible(true);
                    }
                    else {
                        JFrame rootPane = null;
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Cantitatea nu esti disponibila", "Eroare de cumparare", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    JFrame rootPane = null;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Planta, cantitate si pretul nu sunt din aceeasi categorie", "Eroare de cumparare", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }

            }
        });
        panelHome.add(butonCumpara);

        //Cumpurile denumire cantitate si pret pt adaugarea plantei
        //denumireField
        denumireField = new JTextField();
        denumireField.setBounds(80, 240, 100, 20);
        denumireField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

        //placeholder pt denumireField
        final String placeholderDenumire = "Denumire";
        denumireField.setText(placeholderDenumire);
        denumireField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
            private boolean showingPlaceholder = true;
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                if (showingPlaceholder) {
                    showingPlaceholder = false;
                    denumireField.setText("");
                }
            }
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
                if (denumireField.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    denumireField.setText(placeholderDenumire);
                    showingPlaceholder = true;
                }
            }
        });
        panelHome.add(denumireField);

        //cantitateField
        cantitateField = new JTextField();
        cantitateField.setBounds(80, 260, 100, 20);
        cantitateField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

        //placeholder pt cantitateField
        final String placeholderCantitate = "Cantitatea";
        cantitateField.setText(placeholderCantitate);
        cantitateField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
            private boolean showingPlaceholder = true;
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                if (showingPlaceholder) {
                    showingPlaceholder = false;
                    cantitateField.setText("");
                }
            }
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
                if (cantitateField.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    cantitateField.setText(placeholderCantitate);
                    showingPlaceholder = true;
                }
            }
        });
        panelHome.add(cantitateField);

        //pretField
        pretField = new JTextField();
        pretField.setBounds(80, 280, 100, 20);
        pretField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);

        //placeholder pt pretField
        final String placeholderPret = "Pret";
        pretField.setText(placeholderPret);
        pretField.addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {
            private boolean showingPlaceholder = true;
            public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                if (showingPlaceholder) {
                    showingPlaceholder = false;
                    pretField.setText("");
                }
            }
            public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
                if (pretField.getText().isEmpty()) {
                    pretField.setText(placeholderPret);
                    showingPlaceholder = true;
                }
            }
        });
        panelHome.add(pretField);

        //Butonul de adaugare a unei plantei noi
        butonAdauga = new JButton("Adauga");
        butonAdauga.setLocation(180, 260);
        butonAdauga.setSize(100, 20);
        butonAdauga.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                String denumireNou = denumireField.getText();
                String cantitateNou = cantitateField.getText();
                String pretNou = pretField.getText();

                listaplante[kPlante++] = denumireNou;
                listacantitati[kCantitati++] = cantitateNou;
                listapreturi[kPreturi++] = pretNou;
                panelHome.setVisible(false);
                panelHome.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        panelHome.add(butonAdauga);

        //Returnez panelul
        panelHome.setOpaque(true);
        return panelHome;
    }

    public static String[] citirePlante() {
        BufferedReader objReader = null;
        try {
            String strCurrentLine;
            objReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Plante.txt"));
            while ((strCurrentLine = objReader.readLine()) != null) {
                listaplante[kPlante] = strCurrentLine;
                kPlante++;
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (objReader != null) objReader.close();
            } catch(IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return listaplante;
    }

    public static String[] citireCantitati() {
        BufferedReader objReader = null;
        try {
            String strCurrentLine;
            objReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Cantitati.txt"));
            while ((strCurrentLine = objReader.readLine()) != null) {
                listacantitati[kCantitati] = strCurrentLine;
                kCantitati++;
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (objReader != null) objReader.close();
            } catch(IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return listacantitati;
    }

    public static String[] citirePreturi() {
        BufferedReader objReader = null;
        try {
            String strCurrentLine;
            objReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Preturi.txt"));
            while ((strCurrentLine = objReader.readLine()) != null) {
                listapreturi[kPreturi] = strCurrentLine;
                kPreturi++;
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (objReader != null) objReader.close();
            } catch(IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return listapreturi;
    }

    public static void afisPlantaCumparata(String p, int c) throws IOException {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("PlanteVandute.txt", true);
        try (

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writer)) {

            bw.write(p + " " + c + "\n");

        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.err.format("IOException: %s%n", e);
        }
    }

    private static void Home() {

        JFrame frameHome = new JFrame("PLAFAR * Calinescu George-Catalin * 221");

        //Creez panelul peste frame si il stilizez
        Home home = new Home();
        frameHome.setContentPane(home.createHomeContentPane());
        frameHome.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frameHome.setSize(400, 350);
        frameHome.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Creez GUI si il afisez pe ecran
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Home();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is there any method I can add a scroll pane to list, list2 and list3? I really don't want to set another layout type because I'm not used to them and I worked with absolute layout when I started doing this GUI but I ran into some problems and I decided to wrote all the code by hand.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the external file, remove all unnecessary cruft etc. 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: See [How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for a working example. Run the "ListDemo" and click on the "Hire" button to add new names to the list. When the list is full the scrollbars appear automatically. When you use layout managers there is no trick Everything works as expected. Also, the usage of your "static" variables indicates a design problem. There is no need for the static variables.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for providing example code / minimal working example. (One remark - if no `Plante.txt` is found an exception is thrown. You could improve your code to handle this behavior, e.g., with a warning or message for the user.)

You can add your `JList` to a `JScrollPane` like this:

```
// to ensure single selection in your list
someList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(someList);
```

Then, you have to add `scollPane` to a `LayoutManager` or (in your example) `JPanel`.

Comment: *"You could improve your code to handle this behavior.."* Like, hard coding some data? Also, this problem (about layouts) can be described in a lot less than the near 350 lines of code seen above.

Answer (score 0):

It's **strongly recommended to use a normal layout manager**, because layout manager allows to handle components sizes, when Window/Panel is resized. It's also provides better support for different [Look and Feels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html) and OS.

To get your code working you need to install scroll pane around your list.

```
DefaultListModel<String> listaPlante = new DefaultListModel<>();
JList<String> list = new JList<>(citirePlante());
JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(list);
scroller.setBounds(50,75, 75,100); // not list!!!
list.setSelectionBackground(Color.ORANGE);
panelHome.add(scroller); // not list!!!
```

Comment: i read about layout manager but i started with null layout so i want to finish this project with this kind of layout. it's my fault that i didn't searched better when i started to do it.

Comment: anyway, i tried your code and it's doesn't working looks like it's doing sth but it;s not a scroll